# Discord JDA keeps printing [Finalizer] WARN RestAction - Found unclosed resources in MessageAction instance

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, discord-jda

I send an image file to a specific discord channel every minute with Quartz Scheduler.
However, when image file is sent, my bot's console outputs the log below.

```
[Finalizer] WARN RestAction - Found unclosed resources in MessageAction instance, closing on finalization step!
```

Is it possible to disable log? Or did I do something wrong?

Files are sent well, but this log is very annoying because it prints out every time a file is sent to the console.

Here is my code (If you need):

ImageSendingJob.java

```
public class ImageSendingJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        TextChannel textChannel = JDA.guild.getTextChannelById("ID");
        InputStream image = // Image
        textChannel
                .sendFile(image, String.format("%s.png", context.getFireTime()))
                .complete();
    }
}
```

SchedulerManager.java

```
private void startScheduler() {
    SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

        JobDetail job = newJob(ImageSendingJob.class)
                .withIdentity("Job", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
                .build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("JobTrigger", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(60)
                        .repeatForever())
                .build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try updating to the latest version (5.0.0-beta.2)

Comment: @Minn updated it and it was resolved. Thank you!